# Routing exclusion laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem here that needs your help. how to send the form without {{csrf_field()}} to laravel 5.4.

Added his file to the file VerifyCsrfToken.php in the field $except = []; but it does not work. Help please.

Comment: comment your code( \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,) in Kernel file  csrf token

Comment: Yes, I know it but I need to form one form exactly

Comment: Add path or url in **$except** array, not filename. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Answer (score 0):

Add you from route in **VerifyCsrfToken** *Middleware* file in protected **except** array

like this

```
protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
```

further more info check [lavarel csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

hope it will help you.

Comment: if your question is solve by this solution then make it as answer